# How can I save and restore my records in Odoo?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, odoo

What's the best way to export or save the records from the customer modules so you can reuse them if we have trouble with odoo? - If you uninstall and reinstall odoo, the records you created are gone.

It is important to me to find a solution without the EXPORT BUTTON from the UI. Since we have [lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6WcY.png) like this, it doesn't work with the classic button.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First i recommend to you to do a backup. You can create a backup in odoo from
the login page or the url:

```
http://localhost:8069/web/database/selector
```

Or, from your terminal, you can create a dump of your database with:

```
$ pg_dump your_backup_database -Fc > your_backup_database.dump
```

You can restore your database by loading your backup from the Odoo UI or directly into postgres with:

```
$ pg_restore -d your_tmp_database your_database.dump
```

Now, to get back your data in a new Odoo installation, you can export your old data to CSVs files with sql queries and then insert it into your new database. Example:

- To export your customers:

```
--sql
COPY (
    SELECT * 
    FROM customers
) TO '/your_path/customers.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' ENCODING 'your_encoding';
```

- To recover your customers:

```
-- sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_customers(
  id INTEGER,
  name TEXT
);

\COPY temp_customers(id, name) FROM '/path_to_the_copy/old_customers.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

INSERT INTO customers (id, name)
SELECT id, name
FROM temp_customers;
```

Note: Take care of records from other tables that reference this one,
you should also export those records to keep consistency.

Comment: Thank you very much! We have found an extended EXPORT mode where you have many more options to save certain fields via a template. Strangely enough we missed exactly that :D